# bwa mem hangs after a few thousand reads

Tags: sequence-alignment, genome, assembly, variant-calling, bwa

I am trying to align a bunch of paired sample fastq files using bwa mem.

My original command was:

```
bwa mem -t 8 hg38.fa sample_read1.fq.gz sample_read2.fq.gz > sample_paired.sam
```

I am running this on a HPC cluster.

These files have approx. 25 million reads, so I initially anticipated that they might take a little bit of time; however I noticed that the programs seemed to hang - the sam file that I am redirecting the output to never became populated with any entries other than the header comments, even after hours of waiting.

Noticing this, I decided to first test whether the most bare bones bwa mem functionality was working, and so I took just the first 1000 lines off one of the fastq files and tested whether it was working with:

```
bwa mem hg38.fa test_1000lines.fq.gz > test_output.sam
```

So this works. This creates a proper sam file almost instantaneously. However, I kept testing this behavior by increasing the number of lines I took off the fastq file from 1000 to 2000,3000,etc., and eventually realized that any fastq files I input with more than approximately 8400-8500 lines will make the program hang.

If I run the following with a fastq file containing 8400 lines, the program will run and the sam file will be created in a few seconds:

```
bwa mem hg38.fa test_8400lines.fq.gz > test_output8400.sam
```

and this is the stdout output:

```
[M::bwa_idx_load_from_disk] read 0 ALT contigs
[M::process] read 2100 sequences (313733 bp)...
[M::mem_process_seqs] Processed 2100 reads in 1.051 CPU sec, 1.054 real sec
[main] Version: 0.7.17-r1188
[main] CMD: bwa mem supporting_files/hg38.fa test_8-4k.fq.gz
[main] Real time: 4.231 sec; CPU: 4.178 sec
```

However, if I run the following with just 100 more lines in the fastq file:

```
bwa mem hg38.fa test_8500lines.fq.gz > test_output8500.sam
```

The command will hang (at least, that is what it appears like it's doing) and all I will see on the terminal is:

```
[M::bwa_idx_load_from_disk] read 0 ALT contigs
[M::process] read 2125 sequences (317468 bp)...
```

followed by a blinking cursor.

I've monitored the CPU and MEM usage with the "top" command while I was conducting these tests, and while the memory never goes above something like 15%, the CPU usage always goes to 100% when this hanging behavior happens. When the .sam files were created properly and the program didn't hang, the CPU usage was (for the very short amount of time it took for the program to run) like 60-70%.

Whether the CPU usage going to 100% is causing the hanging, or the hanging it causing the CPU usage to 100%, I'm not sure.

I'm completely out of ideas what the issue is here. Any ideas?

EDIT: Although I originally suspected this to be an issue with my fastq file, I observed the stalling behavior with a different fastq file from a completely different source and ruled that out. It turns out the problem is something related to the reference index, since when I use a different set of reference indices (the hs38DH set) instead of the hg38 set that I had been using, the problem disappears.

Comment: The problem with this question is there's no diagnosis. `top` doesn't diagnose the cluster - it diagnoses the head node - where the job *usually* shouldn't be running by convention (cluster depending). RAM allocation between the head node and the worker nodes isn't always the same thing.  The correct command is `htop`. Whats the output of that? `-t` is multi-threading. `htop` will describe the CPU and RAM allocation across every CPU in the cluster - not just one node. Are you are running a queue system and a inhouse cluster (via jobs) or a cloud and partitions with/without job submission?

Comment: Does this always happen or is it specific to these particular reads only?

Comment: @terdon So what I've been able to confirm since I posted this question, is that there are multiple locations in this fastq file where this hanging behavior occurs (for example, if I skip over the first 50k lines and take out a chunk of 10k lines and run bwa mem, then I will once again observe stalling behavior from those 10k lines). It looks like this problem between line 8400 and 8500 just happens to be the first occurrence of the problem. I can also confirm that my other sample fastq files also exhibit this behavior, although at different locations in the file.

Comment: Please edit that into your question. Also tell us what species you are sequencing, how much of it, if your target includes many repetitive or ow complexity regions etc. It really sounds like you're hitting some specific issue but I cannot be sure and maybe if you add more detail someone more knowledgeable than I can figure it out. Even better, try and get the smallest file that reproduces the issue and upload it somewhere we can see it (assuming you are allowed to).

Comment: Cross-posted here: [bwa mem hangs after a few thousand reads](https://www.biostars.org/p/9581378/)

Comment: @terdon So it turns out that if I use a different set of reference indices (for ex. the hs38DH set) as opposed to the hg38 set which I built using "bwa index", then the problem disappears. 

This solves my immediate problem, although I'm curious if you have any insights into why the original hg38 build indices might have caused bwa mem to stall? I have the log from the index build and it does not have any complaints or errors. As far as I can tell, it worked fine.

Comment: I can't know without knowing the exact commands you ran, what kind of preprocessing you did to the genome, which minor version of hg38 etc etc.You could try asking a new question with these details but it will be hard for us to debug without access to the actual data.

Comment: I mean it was literally just these 3 lines:


>wget -P reference/ https://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/bigZips/hg38.fa.gz


>gunzip reference/hg38.fa.gz


>bwa index reference/hg38.fa

Comment: did you md5sum the downloaded references? are you sure the download was complete and not corrupt?